# Jquery - Scroll a DIV(overflow:auto;) with a DIV

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow

how can i scroll a DIV (overflow:auto;) with a DIV?

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:100px; height:200px; border:1px solid #ff0000; overflow:hidden;">
   <div id="my_div" style="width:100%; padding-right:20px; height:100%; overflow:auto;" class="sph">
       <div style=" background-color:#c6c6c6; width:10px; height:20px; position: absolute; left:80px; cursor:pointer;" >S</div>
       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />
       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />
       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />
       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />
       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />
       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />
       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />       .. content ...  <br />       
   </div>

</div>

<br /><br >
  Use the MouseScroll to scroll or use the [S]croll Div
```

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/sbAfW/11/

**Thanks in advance!**

 Peter

Comment: Amm, its seems to be scrolling for me.. what do you want to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [jScrollPane plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

The first demo on [the demo page](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html) is what you might be looking for. You could just remove the background attributes from the jspVerticalBar and jspTrack classes and you're on your way!